# State of React.js component is not updated when browser auto-completes username

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following component in React:

```
class LoginForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {username: '', password: '', redirectToReferrer: false};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const value = event.target.value;
    const name = event.target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.username);
    Auth.authenticate(this.state.username, this.state.password, () => {
      this.setState({ redirectToReferrer: true })
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { from } = this.props.location.state || { from: { pathname: '/' } }
    const { redirectToReferrer } = this.state

    if (redirectToReferrer) {
      return (
        <Redirect to={from}/>
      )
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <p>You must log in to view the page at {from.pathname}</p>
        <form id='loginForm'>
          <input type="text" name="username" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <input type="password" name="password" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Log in</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

When I use the browser auto-complete feature (instead of typing 'admin' I type just 'a' and let browser to fill the rest) the component's state is not update and it submits incorrect value. When I type the username/password all by hand it works correctly. How can I fix this? It's pretty common use case...

Comment: Which browser are you referring to? Tested it in Chrome, it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that some [browsers have a bug](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1159#issuecomment-147550941).

You can try to workaround it with [Autofill polyfill](https://github.com/tbosch/autofill-event):

> A polyfill to fire a change event when the browser auto fills form fields